# Convert a file using system after writing data to it

Tags: c, file-io

I'm facing an issue while converting a file from ascii to ebcdic in C program. what my program does is

```
1. open a file for writing and write required data
2. close the file pointer `fclose(fp)`
3. using system function convert


cmd="dd infile=oldfile outfile=newfile conv=ebcdic
```

Currently after the program execution, converted file doesnt have any data.

```
#define CMD_FORMAT "dd if=%s of=%s conv=ebcdic"
int ascii2ebcdic(char * in, char *out)
{
    char cmd[1000];
    sprintf(cmd,CMD_FORMAT,in,out);
    if(system(cmd) ==0 )
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("ascii","w+");
    fprintf(fp,"ASCII data123\n");
    fclose(fp);
    ascii2ebcdic("ascii","ebcdic");
    return 0;
 }
```

currently the file ebcdic doesn't have any data(0bytes). When i run the same command in the bash console, the data is getting converted.

Can someone point if I'm doing something wrong or I missed anything. Please dont mind my vague description.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you I needed to add a semi colon to the end of the "FILE *fp" line, your program works as expected.  It wrote out a 14 byte file called "ebcdic". I even see the output of the "dd" command showing number of records in/out and bytes written.

Comment: Are you running your code from a directory that you have permission to write to?  It will actually crash if you don't (since fp will be null after fopen call.)

Comment: yes @selbie is right, I think the problem is semi-colon this `FILE *fp`

Comment: please don't use `system`

Comment: @selbie,Adeel Ahmed, i had given ; forgot to paste it here.. the code runs and create the file ascii and ebcdic. but ebcdic dont have any data inside it. ascii as the written data.

Comment: can you paste the output of your command?

Comment: you need to check that when invoking "dd" you are in the same path as the "ascii" file . invoke "ls" for example.

Comment: You should see output from the `dd` command coming to your shell - what is that displaying? When I run your code above it works fine, so there must be something about your setup - I would have expected `dd` to produce error messages for most of the cases I can think of, though.